# Como funciona o licenciamento dos programas Open-Source?

Tags: java, python, licença

Já busquei bastante no Google mas nunca achei uma boa explicação pra como fazer programas open-source. Eu curto muito programar em Java e Python e queria desenvolver algum programa open com essas linguagens, mas imagina se eu crio um programa desses, vem outra pessoa, e copia meu programa e diz que foi ela que fez... Como eu posso ficar seguro contra isso? no geral... Como fazer programas open-source?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

### Direitos de Autor

De acordo com a [Convenção de Berna](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conven%C3%A7%C3%A3o_da_Uni%C3%A3o_de_Berna), certas obras (principalmente artísticas e literárias, mas também científicas - incluindo programas de computador) têm o direito de autor assegurado desde a sua criação. Independentemente se você fez alguma publicação ou registro formal dela ou não.

> A primeira regra é a da não-exigência de qualquer formalidade para obter a proteção. Para países como o Brasil, onde se prevê o registro da obra, este é apenas *ad probandum tantum*, e completamente opcional. Assim, o resultado deste princípio é que - ao contrário do que acontece, por exemplo, com as patentes - o direito exclusivo nasce da criação e não de qualquer declaração estatal, e é garantido sem exigência de qualquer outra formalidade.

- [*ad probandum tantum*](http://www.jusbrasil.com.br/topicos/26390694/ad-probandum-tantum) - "apenas para provar"

### Registro

Como [apontado por sergiopereira](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/29790/215), qualquer um pode pegar seu programa e dizer que foi ele que fez. É necessário então **provar** que você é o verdadeiro autor. A maneira mais garantida é através de um registro oficial - no caso do Brasil, [junto ao INPI](http://www.inpi.gov.br/portal/acessoainformacao/artigo/programa_de_computador_1351692237105). Teoricamente, o procedimento é relativamente simples e barato:

> Nos últimos anos, o registro de programa de computador está ficando mais simples e o código-fonte pode ser enviado em formato PDF.
>
> O pedido de registro de software, com até cinco invólucros, custa R$ 590, caindo para R$ 235 no caso de pessoas naturais; microempresas, empresas de pequeno porte e cooperativas assim definidas em Lei; instituições de ensino e pesquisa; entidades sem fins lucrativos, bem como órgãos públicos.

Mas na prática, como sabemos, um programa de computador não fica "pronto": ele está em constante evolução. Quando, e com que frequência, se deve fazer esse registro, isso é algo que só um advogado poderá te dizer (eu próprio tenho essa dúvida há anos, e ainda não sei ao certo).

### Alternativas?

Se o registro é opcional - sendo sua única (?) utilidade provar a autoria no caso de uma ação judicial - pode-se buscar alternativas a ele. De novo, só um advogado pode te dizer o que serve e o que não serve, mas minha impressão *particular* é que se você fizer uma divulgação bastante pública e aberta - hospedar seu código no GitHub, por exemplo - fica mais fácil provar que ele é realmente seu.

### Licenciamento

Assumindo que você é o autor de um programa - e não produziu o mesmo enquanto funcionário de uma empresa ou situação similar (caso em que os direitos são do seu contratante, não seu) - você possui um "monopólio" em relação a quem pode **copiar** seu programa. Você *poderia* vender/transferir os direitos sobre ele, ou - o que é mais comum - licenciá-lo para que outros tenham o direito de: a) usá-lo; b) estudá-lo; c) modificá-lo; d) redistribuí-lo. Os programas "proprietários" normalmente só dão o direito de usá-lo, mas atualmente está crescendo o número de projetos que [também permitem estudá-lo](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sharedsource/default.aspx).

### Código Aberto ou Software Livre?

Embora os termos "código aberto" (*open source*) e "software livre" (*free software*) sejam usados como sinônimos, eles não querem dizer *exatamente* a mesma coisa: o código é aberto quando a pessoa que recebe o binário (se algum) recebe/tem o direito de receber também o código fonte. O que ela pode fazer com esse código, aí depende do caso...

Já o conceito de software livre também está sujeito a interpretações, mas em geral ele é um programa cujo usuário tem direito de estudá-lo e modificá-lo (o que implica na necessidade da distribuição também dos fontes) e redistribuí-lo para quem ele quiser, sem a necessidade de permissão adicional do seu autor e/ou pagamento de royalties. Algumas modalidades de licenciamento ([*copyleft*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyleft)) exigem que qualquer obra derivada - modificações que você fez no programa, ou outros programas que incluam **e** interajam com o original - seja licenciado da mesma forma ou de modo bastante similar. Outras ([*copyfree*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyfree)) não impõem essa restrição. Qual das duas é "mais livre" é alvo de muita polêmica...

### Respondendo então à pergunta...

Se você deseja desenvolver softwares livres, a primeira coisa a fazer é garantir que os direitos desses softwares sejam seus (não desenvolver a serviço de alguém) e se planejar para provar que eles são seus. Decida o quão importante é prevenir que alguém os "roube", e aja de acordo (publicando-o logo, registrando-o logo, mantendo-o secreto até ter "volume" suficiente pro custo do registro valer a pena, etc).

Em seguida, pense no quão "livre" você quer que o seu programa seja: pra você basta que lhe deem crédito? Use algo como as licenças [BSD](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Licen%C3%A7a_BSD) ou [MIT](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Licen%C3%A7a_MIT) (ou [Apache](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Licen%C3%A7a_Apache), mas na minha opinião ela é complicada além do necessário). Quer garantir que ninguém "se aproveite" do seu programa sem "jogar sob as mesmas regras do jogo"? Use [GNU GPL](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License) ou - no caso de programas no lado servidor - [GNU Affero GPL](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Affero_General_Public_License). Algo no meio do caminho? A [GNU LGPL](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_LGPL) por exemplo permite que seu programa seja linkado com programas não-livres, mas ainda garante que o seu programa em si continue livre.

<sup><sub><sup>(e se estiver pouco ligando pra como vão usar seu programa, a [WTFPL](http://www.wtfpl.net/) é sempre uma opção... :P)</sup></sub></sup>

Você sempre pode usar outra licença, é claro, ou mesmo escrever sua própria licença, nos seus termos específicos (consulte um advogado; e **não copie** uma licença pré-existente e use-a como se fosse sua - os textos das licenças *também* são protegidos por direitos autorais...). Mas se puder evitar, não faça isso: os softwares não existem "numa ilha" - é sempre necessário/interessante integrar programa A com B, embutir A em B, ou estendê-los para outros propósitos. Quanto mais "padronizada" for a licença que você usa, maior a chance de outras pessoas poderem usá-lo sem preocupações - e isso é que é importante no software livre: um colabora de cá, outro de lá, e juntos conseguimos fazer algo que individualmente jamais seríamos capazes de fazer.

Comment: Para enriquecer a resposta, segue um link que pode auxiliar na escolha da licença para seu software: http://choosealicense.com/licenses/

Answer (score 5):

Na verdade você não tem como evitar que alguém copie seu programa e se passe como o verdadeiro autor, especialmente com o código todo disponível.

O que você pode fazer é declarar uma licença de uso para seu código no estilo Open Source. Com isso você estará informando a quem quiser utilizar seu código quais são suas regras para uso do mesmo. A grosso modo, geralmente as licenças Open Source permitem o uso e modificação do seu código contanto que continue sendo atribuído ao autor original, no caso você.

Há vários exemplos conhecidos de licenças Open Source, entre elas GPL, LGPL, MIT, e Apache.

Como eu disse, você não pode evitar a cópia sem atribuição, mas tendo a licença bem clara no site do seu projeto ou mesmo nos próprios arquivos de código-fonte, você tem a possibilidade de exigir até mesmo judicialmente o uso adequado do seu trabalho, caso isso esteja te causando dano de alguma forma.

Answer (score 0):

Em computação, o que se patenteia é a ideia que pode estar expressa em artefatos de software (diagramas, fluxograma, descrições, algoritmos), o código fonte é mera consequência e sujeito a variações tais como correções, aperfeiçoamentos... o que vale é a IDEIA.

Vale o princípio da antecedência, ou seja, quem teve a ideia primeiro. Há duas formas de registrar oficialmente a ideia antes da conclusão da análise do INPI:

1. Enviar uma carta para si mesmo através dos Correios e mantendo o envelope lacrado. A data do carimbo dos Correios é válida como prova. (essa método é antigo e era muito utilizada).
2. Registrar os artefatos de software em cartório. Esboços, desenho, descrição detalhada da ideia.
   Esses dois métodos são válidos para não se correr o risco de, durante a análise de patente, alguém pleitear a ideia, salvo se o pleiteante demonstrar anterioridade.

Dica: Não se patenteia código. Se patenteia ideias.

Comment: Na primeiro método que você mostrou, poderia dar mais detalhes? Tipo, o que teria que ter nessa carta?