# Como funciona o licenciamento de software?

Tags: licença, código-aberto

Eu já procurei bastante no Google mas não achei uma resposta que deixasse tudo claro.

Suponha-se que eu tenho um projeto caseiro e publico esse código num repositório muito famoso, como o [Github](http://github.com). E ele está lá, sob nenhuma licença. Mas eu julguei que o código é de qualidade e eu tenha que expressar e deixar "oficial" que o código está sob aquela licença.

Dentro disso:

- Como eu procederia para expressar e deixar oficial que o meu código está sob determinada licença?
- Que implicações legais isso têm?
- Eu notei que no comentário de licença de um arquivo sempre tem um *copyright*. Se eu sou uma pessoa comum, como eu expresso o meu *copyright*?

Como funciona o licenciamento de software/código em geral?

Comment: Sugiro [essa pergunta relacionada](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/29789/215) para uma visão geral sobre o licenciamento de softwares. Quanto aos seus pontos específicos, concordo com [a resposta do bigown](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/46065/215).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Coloque um arquivo texto simples ou embuta no código expressando as regras da licença. Melhor ainda, use um texto padrão de uma licença padrão.
2. Procure um advogado.
3. Coloque o seu nome e ano. Exemplo: `2015 © Sid`. Isso não tem valor legal se você não puder provar que a autoria é sua, então um registro pode ser necessário também.

Por padrão software sem licença deve ser considerado a forma mais restritiva possível. Ou seja, nem olhe o conteúdo. Você licencia para informar e tranquilizar os possíveis interessados no seu software.

Em geral, no exemplo que você está citando, os desenvolvedores tem mais o cuidado de deixar claro a liberdade para que outras pessoas não se sintam acuadas em utilizar aquele software. Eles não se preocupam muito em garantir direitos até porque eles não pretendem tomar providências se algo for violado. Eles estão disponibilizando sem nenhum interesse comercial, financeiro ou outro tipo de preocupação.

Se isso não for o caso então procure um advogado, pois só ele pode dar informações fiáveis.

[Registro de software](http://www.inpi.gov.br/portal/acessoainformacao/artigo/programa_de_computador_1351692237105). É complicado manter atualizado.

[Lista de licenças comumente utilizadas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_software_licenses).

[Artigo sobre licenças da Wikipedia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Licen%C3%A7a_de_software).

Fora isso, a questão é muito ampla e pede por informações que só um advogado especialista pode fornecer. Pessoas aleatórias sem o conhecimento e habilitação necessária não podem ir além do trivial para lhe informar.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).