# Aplicar licenças ao Github

Tags: github, licença

Tenho aplicações no Github (repositório público) e gostaria de saber se é possível atribuir licenças aos repositórios, e se há alguma licença de software que:

- Garanta que eu sou o autor do software (evitar plágio).
- Restrinja a modificação do software.

Se sim, como faço pra atribuir a licença a minha aplicação?

- Colo algum comentário nos arquivos (tem de ser em todos os arquivos ou colando em um todos estão protegidos?)
- Tenho de registrar os códigos fontes em alguma entidade ?
- Tenho de registrar os arquivos anexos (planilhas que ele usa, dlls próprias)?

Comment: Acho que tem duas perguntas aí e uma delas já foi respondida: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46063/101

Comment: O próprio github, quando você cria o repositório, pergunta a licença, e logo ao lado apresenta um link para um site feito para escolher a licença. Esse site dá informações e dicas de qual licença escolher.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> ...é possível atribuir licenças aos repositórios[...]

**Sim.**

Como o @ RSinohara já disse nos comentários, o próprio GitHub oferece a opção de escolher uma licença ao criar o repositório:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao escolher uma licença dentre as opções pré-existentes, o próprio GitHub já incluirá o arquivo **`LICENSE`** na sua pasta raiz, com os termos da licença escolhida:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para mudar uma licença já atribuída anteriormente, entre no arquivo **`LICENSE`**, e clique no ícone de editar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E então a opção de mudar a licença aparecerá no canto direito:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Também é possível incluir termos adicionais à licença escolhida:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> e se há alguma licença
>   de software que:
>
> Garanta que eu sou o autor do software (evitar plágio). 
>   Restrinja a modificação do software.

Eu não entendi muito bem qual sua intenção (restringir = proibir a utilização no todo ou em parte?), mas pelo visto você não vai querer usar uma licença de software livre.

Então, no Github você deve escolher a opção "None", ou então criar uma licença proprietária, apenas com os termos específicos pelos quais você permite a utilização do código.

Você pode muito bem criar uma licença "pavê", do tipo:

> **Todos os direitos reservados. O autor permite apenas a visualização do código, sendo proibida qualquer utilização do mesmo, no todo ou em parte.**

Mas mesmo que você não use licença alguma, seu código já estará protegido pela Lei do Direito Autoral e a Lei do Programa de Computador.

Vou copiar aqui um trecho de um wiki que estou escrevendo sobre este tema, pra tentar facilitar o entendimento desta parte da pergunta:

...

E quais direitos estão reservados?

A lei divide os direitos de autor em morais e patrimoniais. Os direitos morais são irrenunciáveis e inalienáveis (veja todos os direitos morais do autor no art. 24 da Lei 9.610/98.)

No entanto, no caso específico dos programas de computador, a Lei 9.609/98 manteve apenas dois dos direitos morais do autor:

> § 1º Não se aplicam ao programa de computador as disposições relativas aos direitos morais, **ressalvado, a qualquer tempo, o direito do autor de reivindicar a paternidade do programa de computador e o direito do autor de opor-se a alterações não-autorizadas, quando estas impliquem deformação, mutilação ou outra modificação do programa de computador, que prejudiquem a sua honra ou a sua reputação.**
>   (O final deste parágrafo lembra muito a licença BSD, como veremos adiante)

Dentre os direitos patrimoniais do autor (Lei 9.610/98) estão:

> Art. 29. Depende de **autorização prévia e expressa** do autor a utilização da obra, por quaisquer modalidades, tais como:
>  **I - a
>   reprodução parcial ou integral;
>  II - a edição; [...] 
> VI - a
>   distribuição, quando não intrínseca ao contrato firmado pelo autor com
>   terceiros para uso ou exploração da obra; 
> VII - a distribuição para
>   oferta de obras ou produções mediante cabo, fibra ótica, satélite,
>   ondas ou qualquer outro sistema que permita ao usuário realizar a
>   seleção da obra ou produção para percebê-la em um tempo e lugar
>   previamente determinados por quem formula a demanda, e nos casos em
>   que o acesso às obras ou produções se faça por qualquer sistema que
>   importe em pagamento pelo usuário;**

“Cereja no bolo” da proteção ao direito autoral do programa de computador são as implicações criminais:

> Art. 12. Violar direitos de autor de programa de computador: 
> Pena -
>   Detenção de **seis meses a dois anos ou multa**. 
> § 1º **Se** a violação
>   consistir na reprodução, por qualquer meio, de programa de computador,
>   no todo ou em parte, **para fins de comércio**, sem autorização expressa
>   do autor ou de quem o represente: 
> Pena - Reclusão de **um a quatro anos
>   e multa**.
>  § 2º Na **mesma pena** do parágrafo anterior incorre quem **vende,
>   expõe à venda, introduz no País, adquire, oculta ou tem em depósito,
>   para fins de comércio, original ou cópia de programa de computador,
>   produzido com violação de direito autoral.**

Assim, e resumidamente (o tanto quanto me foi possível) são estes os direitos que as licenças de software livre pretendem “suavizar”.

Para ter estes direitos você não precisa fazer nada, não sendo necessário nenhum tipo de registro para ter os direitos resguardados (mas havendo disputa de autoria você será uma pessoa mais feliz se tiver feito o registro ;) ).

...

> Se sim como faço pra atribuir a licença a minha aplicação?

Sobre isso, além [desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/46065/23400), observe o seguinte (segue mais um trecho do wiki que estou criando):

...

Então, quando você cria um ”programa de computador” (qualquer `Hello word!` da  vida), sua criação está protegida pelas leis [9.610/98](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/leis/L9610.htm) e [9.609/98](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/leis/l9609.htm).

E isso mesmo sem você ter realizado nenhum registro, independentemente de sua vontade:

> **Art. 18. A proteção aos direitos de que trata esta Lei independe de
>   registro.**

O registro no INPI pode ser importante para provar a autoria do programa, mas segundo a Lei é apenas uma opção:

> **Art. 19. É facultado ao autor registrar a sua obra no órgão público
>   definido no caput e no § 1º do art. 17 da Lei nº 5.988, de 14 de
>   dezembro de 1973.**

Existem outras formas possíveis de se provar a autoria de um programa - há quem diga que basta enviar um simples e-mail para si mesmo - mas você pode registrar até em papel num cartório (provando assim a data de publicação e a autoria), ou mesmo simplesmente hospedar num servidor estabelecido e confiável (que eventualmente poderá atestar em juízo a data que os arquivos foram enviados para o servidor).

Porém, como não fica tão caro (relativamente), acredito que o mais indicado seja [registrar pelo INPI](http://www.inpi.gov.br/menu-servicos/programa-de-computador/guia-basico-de-programa-de-computador), já que o Decreto Regulamentador 2256/98 estabeleceu especificamente que

> **“ Art. 1º Os programas de computador poderão, a critério do titular dos respectivos direitos, ser registrados no Instituto Nacional da Propriedade Industrial - INPI.”.**

...

Comment: Eu devo colocar a indicação da licença (na forma de comentário) em todas as classes do meu programa?

Comment: Depende da visibilidade que quer dar a isso. Se não quer arriscar que alguém diga: "ah, mas eu não vi a licença e acabei usando" pode até colocar em todas as pastas. Mas legalmente não faz diferença no caso de uma licença proprietária. A pessoa que utilizar um código sem nenhuma licença já estará infringindo direito autoral. A regra geral é, se não tem licença permitindo, não pode usar. Mas só pra constar, a indicação do choosealicense é que se coloque na pasta raiz um arquivo License, como o GitHub faz automaticamente.

Comment: @ricardo, só pra constar, descobri agora que quando você hospeda no GitHub, já está autorizando a visualização e que outros usuários façam `fork`. Eu não sei bem o que é `fork` (dei uma olhada e pareceu ser como um projeto colaborativo, então não entendi muito bem, porque a pessoa não poderá utilizar, mas poderá transformar num num projeto colaborativo?) mas você certamente deve saber, e poderá decidir se vale mesmo a pena manter no GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

Nosso amigo na resposta anterior disse que o `GitHub` só de você colocar seu projeto, você já aceita o termo de ser um projeto colaborativo. Para resolver isto existem outros repositórios, existe um muito bom, o `BitBucket` ele possibilita ter projetos proprietários onde você poderá colocar uma equipe para trabalhar dentro daquele mesmo projeto, a diferença que o repositório se for escolhido será proprietário.

Comment: Mas talvez seja interessante colocar visível no GitHub para outras pessoas verem como eu escrevo meus códigos (em uma entrevista de emprego por exemplo) mas restringir a modificação e redistribuição do mesmo, não é?

Comment: @IagoBruno sim levando por esta ideia de deixar o código disponível para alguma entrevista ou algo sim, é muito interessante colocar no `GitHub`