# Compatibilidade, legalidade e possíveis problemas na alteração de licença open source

Tags: licença

Fiz fork de um software de código livre atualmente disponibilizado sob a [GPL V2](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html). Tal licença tem alguns empecilhos, por isto, estou buscando formas de atualizar o fruto do fork de forma a ser mais "justo".

O produto fruto do fork (subproduto, digamos assim) continuará sendo disponibilizado de forma livre (coisa que o original não faz, já que a questão `opensource` dele é mais marketing, inclusive o repositório nem é atualizado, enquanto existem atualizações liberadas em forma de updates), mas totalmente reestruturado, removendo features atualmente existentes que não fazem parte do escopo da proposta, inclusão de novas features, atualização para frameworks opensource de mercado, etc.

Até então estou considerando as licenças [Apache 2.0](https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0), [MIT](http://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.html) e [GPL V3](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html) com preferência para a Apache 2.0, devido a fatos como:

- mudanças realizadas podem ser proprietárias, então outras pessoas poderiam gerar do `fork` seus próprios produtos, apenas mantendo os créditos;
- não é `copyleft`, acredito que isto diminuiria a barreira na adoção de todo ou partes do produtos tanto em outras iniciativas, tanto opensource quanto proprietárias;

Procurei bastante sobre esta "migração", mas não encontrei nada relevante, apenas comparativos breves sobre as licenças em questão.

Olhei o caso Hudson/Jenkins, um cenário bem parecido do meu, mas o Hudson estava sob a licença do [MIT](http://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.html), bem mais simples, sendo alterada para a [Eclipse Public License - v 1.0](http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html) e o Jenkins continuando na [MIT](http://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.html).

Não conheço muito bem sobre licenciamente de software com código aberto, então tenho bastante dúvidas e quero começar com as seguintes nesta questão:

- Há algum problema em alterar, no subproduto, a licença de um software open source?
- Quais problemas posso ter com a alteração e como evitá-los, considerando o cenário citado?
- Considerando os problemas, qual seria uma possível alternativa usar duas licenças, [GPL V2](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html) pra o que foi "forkado" e [GPL V3](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html)/[Apache 2.0](https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0) para as novas funcionalidades/características?

Qualquer ajuda é bem-vinda =)

Comment: A licença GPL especifica que qualquer "obra derivada" tem de estar sujeita aos mesmos termos da obra original. se `A` é GPL e você desenvolveu `B`, você pode licenciar `B` como quiser, mas `A + B` *precisa* ser GPL. Isso é intencional. Nem todo mundo gosta disso (eu por exemplo não gosto), mas é uma decisão estratégica por parte do autor, e precisa ser respeitada.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @mgibsonbr. Por exemplo, se eu tenho `X` que é GPL, gero `X'` derivado de `X` e tudo que é novo em `X'` estará sob, por exemplo, ASF, se num dado momento em `X'` eu não tenho mais um subconjunto de `X`, mas apenas coias novas, `X'` ainda precisa ser GPL ou pode ser agora todo ASF? Não sei se fui claro aqui rs

Comment: Se eu entendi bem, você partiu de `x` (GPL), alterou para `x + x'0`, depois pra `x + x'0 + x'1`, `x + x'0 + x'1 + x'2`... Onde cada `x'n` é de sua autoria. Eventualmente você tirou `x` da equação: `x'0 + x'1 + x'2 + ... + x'n = x'` - 100% do código é de sua autoria. *Teoricamente* então, você poderia licenciar como quiser (*ideias* não são *copyrighted*, somente expressões concretas das mesmas). O difícil é conseguir isso na prática - sempre vai sobrar algo na sua base que veio de `x`. Enquanto `x'` for **derivado** de `x`, o conjunto deve ser GPL.

Comment: P.S. O que é ou não é uma "obra derivada" é algo que a **justiça** deve decidir. A FSF considera que basta você linkar algo na memória com seu programa GPL para o conjunto ser considerado uma obra derivada, mas nem todo mundo concorda com isso. Essa complexidade que me desestimula de me envolver com o GPL, ainda que concorde com os princípios éticos por trás. Por mais útil que um código GPL seja, eu nunca o incorporo nos meus projetos a menos que eu esteja disposto a também usar GPL (o que até agora tem sido: nunca... :P)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eu não sei te ajudar nos detalhes específicos, para sua segurança sugiro que consulte um advogado. Entretanto, gostaria de esclarecer alguns princípios gerais sobre as tais licenças *copyleft* para ajudar a te orientar a respeito do seu uso.

## Reciprocidade

Quando um autor de um software decide disponibilizar um produto como software livre - abrindo mão do direito concedido por lei de receber *royalties* sobre o mesmo - ele o faz por algum motivo. A princípio, poderia ser simplesmente a disposição de contribuir com a comunidade, sem receber nada em troca, mas nem sempre. Muitos esperam sim algo em troca: a **reciprocidade** de quem recebe uma cópia do seu produto em manter o mesmo livre.

[Segundo a Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyleft#History), Richard Stallman havia trabalhado em um interpretador Lisp por alguns anos, e concordou em disponibilizá-lo à Symbolics via domínio público (i.e. abrindo mão do seu direito de autor, irrestritamente). A Symbolics aprimorou esses interpretador, mas quando Stallman requisitou acesso à versão aprimorada seu pedido foi recusado. A concepção da licença GPL seguiu-se praticamente em seguida (primeiro uma mais restrita, para o Emacs, depois uma de propósito mais geral, a GNU), com o intuito de evitar esse tipo de situação.

A reciprocidade exigida é bem simples, em princípio: eu te dou bastante liberdade em usar meu software, sem cobrar nada [recorrentemente] por ele, e em troca você concorda em fazer o mesmo caso venha a aprimorá-lo de alguma forma **e redistribuí-lo** (aprimorar para uso privado não te obriga a fazer nada). Algumas licenças *copyleft* (tipo a Affero GPL) também exigem que o acesso aos fontes seja dado ainda que o mesmo seja oferecido como SaaS.

Você pode considerar esses requisitos razoáveis ou não, isso é com a opinião de cada um (bem como cada um tem uma opinião diferente quanto à moralidade de se cobrar pela mera cópia de um software, que pode ser feita com custo virtualmente zero). Mas o fato é que quem licenciou espera essa reciprocidade, no papel, e a princípio está pronto para mover uma ação legal contra quem não honrá-la (e com o apoio de diversas organizações que defendem o software livre, como a FSF).

## Ferindo a reciprocidade

Ok, mas e se eu disponibilizar minha versão aprimorada sob uma licença *mais permissiva* que o GPL, não estarei mantendo a reciprocidade? Afinal, eu dei a meus usuários todas as liberdades que seu produto original deu, e mais algumas... Infelizmente, não é tão simples assim. Considere o seguinte cenário:

- Alice disponibiliza `A` como GPL;
- Bob aprimora `A`, e disponibiliza `B` como MIT;
- Charlie aprimora `B`, e disponibiliza `C` sob uma licença proprietária;
- Alice pede a Charlie os fontes de `C`; Charlie nega;
- Alice processa Bob por violação de direitos autorais, pois seu uso de `A` viola os termos da licença do mesmo.

Você poderia pensar "mas o que Alice escreveu ainda é livre, o que não é livre é só o que Charlie escreveu, então ela está reclamando de que?", mas considere que pra Alice pode ser interessante **estrategicamente** que seu sistema permaneça livre. Talvez ela não ganhe diretamente com licenças, mas ela pode ganhar seu sustento prestando serviços em cima do seu produto. Se um concorrente chega com um produto melhor, ela corre o risco de ficar sem trabalho.

O "X" da questão aqui é que Charlie não simplesmente desenvolveu algo melhor que Alice, e colheu os frutos do seu próprio trabalho: ele usou o produto de Alice como "degrau" para se estabelecer como competidor da mesma.

Se esse tipo de coisa fosse tão fácil, a quantidade de software livre no mercado dificilmente seria tão numerosa. Pois ele ficaria restrito a hobbistas em suas horas vagas, os profissionais acabariam por seguir o modelo proprietário mesmo, em que sua perspectiva de retorno é mais garantida.

## *Edge cases*

O GNU GPL foi escrito com bastante cuidado para evitar todo tipo de abuso que explora "buracos" na lei. A versão 3 inclui por exemplo proteções contra a "tivoização" (embutir software livre no hardware ou firmware, impedindo na prática sua modificação), ou o uso de patentes para garantir o monopólio de uma aplicação a despeito das condições de sua licença, etc. O princípio por trás do *copyleft* é importante pra muita gente, de modo que eu não subestimaria a capacidade (e disposição) dos mesmos a correr atrás dos seus direitos.

Respondendo então aos seus pontos questionados:

> Há algum problema em alterar, no subproduto, a licença de um software open source?

Para o GPL, sim. Em geral os softwares são feitos com a premissa que serão modificados, recombinados e/ou incorporados com outros softwares, então as licenças já buscam tratar desse cenário ainda que brevemente. Licenças *copyfree* em geral não exigem muito nesse cenário, exceto uma correta atribuição da fonte (i.e. não negar a autoria do original). Mas pras *copyleft* isso é importante sim.

Você não pode "relicenciar" algo do qual você não detém os direitos de autor. No mundo do *copyright* a redistribuição é a exceção, não a regra, de modo que é preciso ter em mente que a permissão que a GPL te dá de redistribuir não é um **direito** seu, e sim um **privilégio** concedido em troca de uma **contrapartida**. Se você não concorda ou não está disposto a dar essa contrapartida, você perde o privilégio de poder redistribuir o subproduto. É simples assim.

> Quais problemas posso ter com a alteração e como evitá-los, considerando o cenário citado?

Como explicado, redistribuir não é um direito seu, e sim um privilégio, de modo que se você não cumprir com o estabelecido na licença você perde esse privilégio, e sua redistribuição passa a consistir **infração de direitos autorais**. As consequências disso, eu diria que é mais ou menos as mesmas que você fazer uma cópia do Microsoft Windows e redistribuí-la... Conceitualmente, pelo menos, pra ter certeza só um especialista nessas questões jurídicas poderia dizer.

Como evitá-los, simples: não viole os termos da licença GPL. Se seu produto é uma "obra derivada" de um sistema GPL, seja no sentido mais técnico (qualquer programa que execute no mesmo espaço de endereçamento que o programa GPL) ou num sentido mais amplo, em conformidade com as disposições legais da sua região (no Brasil, a [Lei Nº 9.610](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/leis/l9610.htm)), e você optar por redistribuí-lo, faça isso também sob a licença GPL, mesma versão ou - se o produto tiver sido licenciado como "GPL versão 2 *ou superior*" - uma versão superior.

> Considerando os problemas, qual seria uma possível alternativa usar duas licenças, GPL V2 pra o que foi "forkado" e GPL V3/Apache 2.0 para as novas funcionalidades/características?

Aí depende: essas "novas funcionalidades/características" são auto-contidas ou não? Em outras palavras, na ausência do software original, seja embutido ou usado em conjunto, seu sistema cumpre seu propósito, faz algo de útil? Se sim, então ele é um sistema à parte, e sendo de sua autoria você pode licenciá-lo como bem entender. Caso contrário, ele ainda é considerado uma obra derivada do original, então precisa cumprir os termos do produto original.

As possibilidades de estruturar seu sistema de modo que sejam ou não sejam independentes do original são bastante diversas, de modo que é difícil afirmar qualquer coisa assim no abstrato. No entanto, tenha em mente que você está pisando em terreno perigoso, caso opte por se desviar do modelo de licenciamento estabelecido pelo autor original.

Comment: Excelente resposta cara. Passo a considerar agora a fazer um "do zero", já que no outro seriam necessárias tantas modificações que acho que inviabiliza. Basicamente, apenas partes do modelo de dados permaneceriam as mesmas no software derivado "final".

Answer (score 5):

**Não**

Sua fork do projeto ainda é um trabalho derivado que está vinculada pelas restrições GPL. Isto significa que você teria que liberá-lo, nas mesmas condições da GPL. Você não pode liberar ele sob outra licença.

> **Nota:** Eu não tenho conhecimento da licença toda

Acredito que o ponto que fala mais explicitamente que isto não é permitido, seria este:

> 1. You may copy and distribute verbatim copies of the Program's
>      source code as you receive it, in any medium, provided that you
>      conspicuously and appropriately publish on each copy an appropriate
>      copyright notice and disclaimer of warranty; keep intact all the
>      notices that refer to this License and to the absence of any warranty;
>      and give any other recipients of the Program a copy of this License
>      along with the Program.

Traduzindo:

> **Nota:** A tradução pode não ser "precisa"
>
> 1. Você pode copiar e distribuir cópias do Programa de
>      código-fonte ao recebê-lo, por qualquer meio, desde que você
>      conspícua e apropriadamente publique em cada cópia um adequado
>      aviso de direitos autorais e exoneração de garantia; manter intactos todos os
>      avisos que se referem a esta Licença e à ausência de qualquer garantia;
>      e forneça a outros recebedores do Programa uma cópia desta Licença
>      junto com o Programa.

Mais precisamente este: (*manter intactos todos os
avisos que se referem a esta Licença*)

E na segunda seção da licença temos isto:

> But when you distribute the same sections as part of a whole which is
>   a work based on the Program, the distribution of the whole must be on
>   the terms of this License

Você não pode criar uma sub-classe que se comunique com a classe pai (que está GPL), a sub-classe também que ser GPL e pelo meu entendimento, está dificuldade é o motivo de existir a licença LGPL.

**GPL**

Outros desenvolvedores podem emprestar e modificar o código e redistribuí-lo como parte de seu próprio projeto, apenas se todo o seu projeto também está licenciado sob a GPL.

*Isto impede que o código de ser usado em software proprietário.*

**LGPL**

Outros desenvolvedores podem ser emprestados e modificar o código e redistribuí-lo como parte de seu próprio projeto, desde que a parte utilizada sob a LGPL é re-licenciado sob a LGPL. Outras partes do projeto são permitidas têm outras licenças.

Isto permite que o código a ser utilizado de forma proprietária.

> **Nota:** Na questão do GPL o que se comunica com ele é que tem que ser GPL também e por este motivo talvez o Google na questão do Android tenham encontrado tal brecha, só não tenho detalhes de como fazer.

<s>Eu acredito, que se tal fork open-source fosse apenas um arquivo `py` (Python) chamado `produtoemgpl.py`, com este conteúdo:</s>

```
class ProdutoEmGPL:

    @staticmethod
    def metodoA(str):
        ...

    @staticmethod
    def metodoB(str):
        ...
```

E você queira adicionar novas funcionalidades sob outra licença, você deveria criar um novo arquivo e estender a classe pai, o nome do arquivo seria `minhaclasse.py` e este seria sob a sua outra licença:

```
import ProdutoEmGPL

class MinhaClasse(ProdutoEmGPL):

    @staticmethod
    def metodoA(str):
        ...

    @staticmethod
    def metodoB(str):
```

(*Eu pessoalmente acho um tanto quanto injusto, você querer mudar a licença, independente do quanto você se sente injustiçado por não ter os updates no repositório.*)

Sobre o tal produto, eu acredito que eles devem distribuir o produto do tipo "comunidade" e para uso comercial por exemplo, você deve adquirir uma outra licença deles mesmos (por exemplo comprando, mas ainda sim você não poderá mudar a licença provavelmente)

> Nota: Se discordar de mim por favor negative ou feche, realmente não tenho muito conhecimento sobre tal licença.

**Extra**: [Como funciona o licenciamento dos programas Open-Source?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/29789/3635)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Guilherme. Não é questão de injustiça, mas apenas disponibilizar algo que de fato signifique pra a comunidade. Veja o caso do Android quando o Google adotou a ASF, por exemplo. Sobre o que você disse, pode citar fontes, excertos, etc?

Comment: OK, obrigado Guilherme. Irei ver sua resposta com cuidados e ver como combinar as licenças. Realmente entendo que não posso simplesmente pegar `X` que é GPL, gerar `X'` e este último ser ASF, ou algo do tipo. Talvez a pergunta não esteja não claro, irei verificar, mas a intenção não é mudar o que já está licenciado sob GPL, mas sim oferecer as novidades em `X'` sob outra licença. Por exemplo, tudo antigo ou ajustado em `X` continua GPL, tudo novo em `X'` sob outra licença. Aí, no fim, pode ser que tenha tudo sob outra licença, entende?

Comment: No android, à época, teve uma grande discussão da forma que ele seria licenciado, uma vez que está sob coisas em GPL, como o kernel. Então eles meio que "dividiram", algumas coisas são GPL (como contribuições no kernel) e o que foi comprado é ASF. Enfim, era apenas um caso que em partes é parecido. No meu caso é um produto, mas não compilado, há versões antigas do código disponibilizado. O contexto é bastante próximo do Hudson/Jenkins que citei, diferindo nas licenças.

Comment: @BrunoCésar Eu realmente não sei se este é o melhor caminho, mas a minha última edição é uma suposição do que acredito que você possa fazer, mas talvez você possa consultar mais alguém.

Comment: Legal Guilherme, muito obrigado. Vamos esperar e ver se mais alguém dê mais boas sugestões como as suas, obrigado mesmo.

Comment: No meu entendimento, ao simplesmente importar o sistema GPL você está fazendo com que ambos ocupem o mesmo espaço de endereçamento na memória, e *segundo a FSF* (não necessariamente segundo a justiça) isso constitui uma "obra derivada". O conjunto teria então que ser distribuído segundo a GPL.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Sim parece que você está correto, ao meu entendimento, você pode distribuir B em uma outra licença sim, mas não pode distribuir junto com o A (que está em GPL), o usuário teria que baixar por ele o "A". Este foi o meu entendimento. Se eu estiver não estiver enganado esta questão é um dos motivos de existir a licença LGPL.

Comment: Não é bem assim, não há problema em distribuir softwares livres e não livres num mesmo conjunto (num CD, por exemplo), o problema é os dois softwares interagirem um com o outro - independentemente da forma como eles foram distribuídos.

Comment: @mgibsonbr então o problema realmente é na comunicação entre eles. Só uma teoria, eu sei que discussões aqui não é legal, mas vou poder uma suposição: Se eu tiver "A" (GPL) e "B" (GPL - desenvolvido por mim) e este B gerar dados para um arquivo json por exemplo, então eu teria "C" (MIT) que pegaria este json, isto não seria uma comunicação direta e seria permitido?

Comment: *Comunicação* mesmo não é um problema, inclusive se um sistema não livre quiser invocar um livre via fork/exec ou vice-versa, passando dados via *stdin* e lendo a resposta via *stdout*, a GPL permite. São integrações mais fortes, que poderiam inviabilizar a separação dos dois,  que são problemáticas.