# Posso vender um subproduto de um produto sob a Licença Apache 2.0?

Tags: licença

Estou trabalhando em um projeto com [OpenCart](http://www.opencart.com/) (como *freelancer*) e preciso utilizar uma determinada extensão, porém a extensão está desatualizada (em relação ao OpenCart) e licenciada sob Apache 2.0.

Então estava pensando em Atualizar a extensão para o OpenCart 2.0 e vende-la na loja de extensões do OpenCart, porém não sei se a licença Apache 2.0 permite isso.

Estive lendo essas duas perguntas e suas respostas:

- [Compatibilidade, legalidade e possíveis problemas na alteração de licença open source](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/59904/compatibilidade-legalidade-e-poss%C3%ADveis-problemas-na-altera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-licen%C3%A7a-open-s)
- [Como funciona o licenciamento dos programas Open-Source?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29789/como-funciona-o-licenciamento-dos-programas-open-source)

Então me deparei com essa frase na segunda pergunta:

> [...] pense no quão "livre" você quer que o seu programa seja: pra você basta que lhe deem crédito? Use algo como as licenças BSD ou MIT (ou **Apache**, mas na minha opinião ela é **complicada além do necessário**). [...] — [Resposta do @migsombr](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/29801/8493).

Então **queria saber quais são essas complicações** citadas. **A licença Apache permite vender um subproduto derivado de um produto sob sua licença?**

Por exemplo, na licença diz o seguinte:

> You may add Your own copyright statement to Your modifications and may provide additional or different license terms and conditions for use, reproduction, or distribution of Your modifications, or for any such Derivative Works as a whole, provided Your use, reproduction, and distribution of the Work otherwise complies with the conditions stated in this License.

Que "eu traduzi" utilizando o Google Translate:

> Você pode adicionar sua própria declaração de direitos autorais para suas modificações e pode fornecer termos de licença adicionais ou diferentes e condições de utilização, reprodução ou distribuição das suas modificações, ou por quaisquer Obras Derivadas como um todo, desde a sua utilização, reprodução e distribuição do trabalho de outra forma a cumprir as condições estabelecidas nesta Licença.

Ou seja, ela permite que eu redistribua a "Obra Derivada" com outros termos de licença, mas que deve cumprir as condições da licença atual. Não consegui assimilar bem a segunda parte com a primeira, pois não percebi quais são essas condições citadas.

Outro material que li foi o [ChooseALicense](http://choosealicense.com/licenses/), onde diz que a Licença Apache permite uso comercial, e sub-licenciamento. Ou seja, posso sub-licenciar a Obra Derivada e vendê-la?

**No fim das contas, a licença Apache 2.0 permite ou não a venda de uma Obra Derivada?**

Comment: Voce ta com medo da licenca do Apache nao seja compativel com a licenca do OpenChart? Eu acho que nao iria trazer nenhuma complicacao para voce, apenas se voce usar algum pedaco de codigo que nao seja seu e esteja a vendelo e que pode trazer as tais "complicacoes".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Sim.**

A licença Apache 2.0 é uma licença da categoria **`permissiva`** (dentro desta divisão em categorias também existem as **`recíprocas totais`** e as **`recíprocas parciais`**).

Basicamente, as únicas exigências da licença Apache 2 são a divulgação da licença junto com o código, e a indicação de mudanças significativas, não sendo necessário nem ao menos a liberação do código fonte.

Veja os detalhes:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte da imagem: [Escolha uma licença](http://escolhaumalicenca.com.br/licencas/)

E [aqui](http://escolhaumalicenca.com.br/licencas/apache/) você pode ver a licença na íntegra (em inglês).

PS.: Só pra constar, esta proibição de uso de marca registrada se refere à marca Apache (e às marcas de outros colaboradores), não a sua marca. Simplificando, você obviamente não pode usar a marca Apache (ou marcas de outros colaboradores) em seu programa, mas seu programa pode ter uma marca própria sem problemas.